# How to achieve page transitions effect in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am new to wpf.
Need to show every page with a transition like fade and it should move from
left to right.
suggest the way to acheive this.

Here is the link i tried  [demo](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/199014/Page-Transition-Control-for-WPF).

Here in this they used an usercontrol in which they are showing the usercontrol with transtions effects.

But my application has more than 15 pages.
So making all pages as user control is not good.

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `TransitionPresenter` control in the [WPF Bag of tricks](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/bot)

Basic usage:

```
 <bot:TransitionPresenter Content="{Binding SomeViewModelForWhichYouHaveADataTemplateDefined}">
      <bot:TransitionPresenter.Transition>
          <bot:FadeTransition Duration="00:00:00.3"/>
      </bot:TransitionPresenter.Transition>
  </bot:TransitionPresenter>
```